# Laravel 5 forbiddenResponse not working from FormRequest class?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect user to a specific URI after validation fails at authorize() function within a FormRequest class.

```
class CustomUserRequest extends FormRequest {
  public function authorize(Request $request)
  {
    // Prepare POST data
    $post = $request->input();

    // Prepare model
    $user = new UsersModel();
    $userData = $user->where('email', $post['email'])->first();

    if(!$userData && $userData == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // Prepare response
        $this->response['message'] = 'Email already exists.';

        return false;
    }
  }

  // Override unauthorized response
  public function forbiddenResponse() {
    // Return response
    return redirect('register');
  }
}
```

Was wondering if the return is false from authorize() function why isn't forbiddenResponse() override activated?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in request form u can use redirector property

```
public function forbiddenResponse()
{
    return $this->redirector->route('homepage');
}
```